# jQuery - disable scrolling body, enable scrolling div

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I'm creating a mobile app, and I'm trying to do this: I want a pop-up to open, which will work as an auto-suggest feature. The user enters a search term, and in a div below the input there are items corresponding to the user's search.

Now, when the pop-up is open I don't want the user to be able to scroll the main app, I only want him to be able to scroll inside the div with search results.

```
<div id="popUpWrapper">
                <div id="popUp">

                    <div class="row">
                        <input type="text" class="textInput" placeholder="Search" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="results" data-title="Results">
                            <div class="frame">
                                <div class="row postItem">
                                    Example search result
                                </div>
                                <div class="row postItem">
                                    Example search result.
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

`#popUpWrapper` is an overlay dimmer with 100% width and height. With jQuery I disable scrolling on it by binding the `touchmove` event to `return false`. However, this also disabled the scrolling in the `#results` div. It didn't help to unbind the event from that selector. If I don't bind the event I can scroll in the #results but then the main app also scrolls.

Is there an easy fix that I'm missing or should I just leave it scrolling?

Comment: fyi: "I only want him to be able to scroll inside the div with search results." - By doing this, you are instantly alienating almost all iPad / iPhone users. They cannot scroll inside of a div with any sort of accuracy because the scrollbar does not even show up. It is a bug.

Comment: Huh.. Wasn't aware of that - can't they scroll by sliding up/down the div? They have to use the scrollbar?

Comment: The scrollbar is not even present. More than that, the OS for those devices has issues determining that you are scrolling in the div versus the page. It is a nightmare as a user on an iPad or iPhone to be forced to scroll a subsection of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The question's comments already pointed out that this kind of implementation has some weaknesses.

Therefore, I'd suggest to create a header and a footer and position both with `position: fixed` while the main search content will basically stay untouched (besides some kind of top and bottom padding to make space for the header and the footer).

Comment: True, but for the sake of the design, I'd still like to know the answer, regardless of the Applee users. I'll find a different solution for them.

Comment: Actually I made a scroll inside a div in iOS, ti works fine and I'd like also to know the answer to this, cause the page scrolling of jQUery Mobile is causing the application to blink in iOS when the user's reaching the bottom